# Installing a precompiled library that depends on another in a bitbake recipe

Tags: shared-libraries, pytorch, yocto, bitbake, precompiled

I am trying to include pytorch/libtorch in our Yocto-based distribution and running into troubles when it comes to installing precompiled libraries with dependencies among them onto the target.

After trying to compile `pytorch` from source [to no avail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956555/yocto-warrior-bitbake-recipe-for-pytorch-for-nvidia-jetson-nano) I thought I could use the [pre-compiled shared libraries](https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-1.2.0.zip) and move onto the next problem. This however proves so far more difficult than initially anticipated.

Specifically, one of the shared libraries I'd like to install, `libtorch.so` depends on another shared library distributed along it `libgomp-753e6e92.so.1`. When running `ldd` it looks something like this:

```sh
$ ldd libtorch.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc27bcb000)
    libgomp-753e6e92.so.1 => /home/user/Desktop/libtorch-1.2.0/libtorch/lib/./libgomp-753e6e92.so.1 (0x00007f3052954000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3052735000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f305252d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3052315000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3052111000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3051d73000)
    libc10.so => /home/user/Desktop/libtorch-1.2.0/libtorch/lib/./libc10.so (0x00007f3051b2c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f30517a3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f30513b2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f305ef4a000)
```

The bitbake recipe that tries to put everything into place looks like this:

```
SUMMARY = "Facebook PyTorch AI"
DESCRIPTION = "Facebook PyTorch AI"
HOMEPAGE = "https://pytorch.org/"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=acf4d595f99e159bf31797aa872aef57"

S = "${WORKDIR}/libtorch"
LOCAL_INCLUDE = "${S}/include"
LOCAL_LIB = "${S}/lib"
TARGET_INCLUDE = "${D}${includedir}"
TARGET_LIB = "${D}${libdir}"

SRC_URI = "\
    https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-${PV}.zip \
    file://LICENSE \
"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "f34c5b6e46331f79100cd93522bad3ae"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "already-stripped"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""

# RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libgomp"

do_install() {
    # Create include directory
    install -d ${TARGET_INCLUDE}
    # Copy all header files
    cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${LOCAL_INCLUDE}/* ${TARGET_INCLUDE}

    # Create library directory
    install -d ${TARGET_LIB}
    # Install shared libraries
    install -m 0755 ${LOCAL_LIB}/*.so* ${TARGET_LIB}
}

FILES_${PN} += "\
    ${includedir}/* \
    ${libdir}/* \
"
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error telling me that nothing ir *rproviding* the `libgomp` library which is required by `libtorch`.
I have tried multiple things including putting the library in question in its own recipe, explicitly installing it or using the already provided `libgomp` runtime dependency but without any luck so far. The error is always something in the likes of:

```
ERROR: pytorch-1.2.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libtorch.so contained in package pytorch requires libgomp-753e6e92.so.1(GOMP_4.0)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_pytorch? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: pytorch-1.2.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libtorch.so contained in package pytorch requires libgomp-753e6e92.so.1(OMP_1.0)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_pytorch? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: pytorch-1.2.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libtorch.so contained in package pytorch requires libgomp-753e6e92.so.1()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_pytorch? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: pytorch-1.2.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libtorch.so contained in package pytorch requires libgomp-753e6e92.so.1(GOMP_1.0)(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_pytorch? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: pytorch-1.2.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: pytorch-1.2.0-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
```

Any clues on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Due to a lack of a better solution, we compiled our own `libtorch` from source while setting the `USE_OPENMP` environment variable to `OFF`. We still cannot determine why this dependency to a versioned library gave us so much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RPROVIDES_${PN}` solved this issue for me.

```
RPROVIDES_${PN} = "libgomp-753e6e92.so.1(GOMP_1.0)(64bit) \
                   libgomp-753e6e92.so.1(GOMP_4.0)(64bit) \
                   libgomp-753e6e92.so.1(OMP_1.0)(64bit) \
                   libgomp-753e6e92.so.1(OMP_4.5)(64bit)"
```